# Cron is not working in codeigniter

Tags: cron, codeigniter-2

Hi Now i running my cron in putty, I have created the cron using crontab command and i list using crontab -l but still my cron not running it does not update the value in database.[image]

Comment: cron uses a minimal environment variables. Please specify full path of your PHP as a starter and then further troubleshoot, if you script is using any more environment variable make sure those are set before execution of scrip

Comment: sorry i already try this.